# RadGanttView Progress

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I'm using a `RadGanttView`. Here's my code:

```
foreach (string[] data in CreatedClasses.Data_Control.scheduleList)
{
    GanttViewDataItem item = new GanttViewDataItem();
    item.Start = DateTime.Parse(data[4]); item.End = DateTime.Parse(data[5]);
    item.Title = data[2]; item.Tag = data[0]; item.Progress = decimal.Parse(data[9]);
    ganttChartSched.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Now I want to disable the user from choosing a progress lower than the set progress of the item.

Can anyone help me on this please. I can't seem to find an event for ItemProgressChanging.

Answer (score 0):

Users can change the progress via the context menu. So, you will need to modify it in order to prevent the undesired percentages. I will suggest hiding the default Progress item and adding your own. Here is an example:

```
    void radGanttView1_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, GanttViewContextMenuOpeningEventArgs e)
    {
        GanttViewDefaultContextMenu ganttMenu = ((GanttViewDefaultContextMenu)e.Menu);
        ganttMenu.ShowProgress = false;

        RadMenuItem progressItem = new RadMenuItem("Progress");
        e.Menu.Items.Add(progressItem);

        for (decimal i = 0; i <= 100; i += ganttMenu.ProgressStep)
        {
            GanttViewMenuItem menuItem = new GanttViewMenuItem(i.ToString(), string.Format("{0:P0}", i / 100));
            progressItem.Items.Add(menuItem);
            menuItem.IsChecked = e.Item.Progress == i;
            menuItem.Click += progressMenuItem_Click;

            menuItem.Enabled = i > e.Item.Progress;
        }
    }

    private void progressMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GanttViewMenuItem item = (GanttViewMenuItem)sender;
        radGanttView1.GanttViewElement.SelectedItem.Progress = int.Parse(item.Command);
    }
```